# Upgrading SVN after new Windows installation

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've been running `Tortoise SVN` for awhile now and have been using `V1.6.8`. I just bought a new HD so decided it was about time I upgraded SVN as well and I just downloaded `V1.8.1`

My OLD SVN was installed at: `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN`

My NEW one will be installed at: `G:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN` as I accidentally installed Windows to the `G` drive and `C:` is currently occupied by my old drive which will be removed soon.

**All my repositories will remain in the same place as well as all the versioned files/folders.**

So my question is, is there anything I need to worry about when doing the upgrade? Such as path information considering it will be installed at a new location? What is the process I need to follow?

I want to keep my old settings etc so I am wanting to keep the data inside the `Application Data\TortoiseSVN` folder but not sure if this would be compatible with the new version?

I'm thinking something like this..

- Install Old Version to `G:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN`
- Copy over old data in `Application Data\TortoiseSVN` to new dir
- Install new version

Would that do it? or as above are there path issues or other things to consider?

Answer (score 2):

> is there anything I need to worry about when doing the upgrade?

Yes

> Such as path information considering it will be installed at a new location?

No. Installation will add `TortoiseSVN\bin` to PATH automatically, shell-extension does not depend from installation location

You really have to worry about two (different, unrelated to mentioned) things

- Subversion configuration have to be copied to the new location of Subversion-data (stored auths, configuration, server-specific settings) - they are always in `%APPDATA%\Subversion` and have to be moved from C to G
- Working Copy of Subversion 1.8 use new format, incompatible with 1.6 (1.8 can't read WCs of 1.6), you must `svn upgrade` all old Working Copies (or re-checkout to new location)

Comment: So exactly what steps do I need to take? Copy `%APPDATA%\Subversion` to new location? After this do I install the new version or old version? If I install new version do I then run the `svn upgrade` on all working copies?

Comment: @Brett: 0. Install **new** version into **new** location. In *any* order (but *before* using local WC, related to restricted server): * `svn upgrade` * `copy /Y "c:\Documents and Settings\<USER>\Application Data\Subversion" "c:\Documents and Settings\<USER>\Application Data\Subversion"`

Comment: I assume you made a mistake in the above and were meant to copy `c:\` to `G:\`?

Comment: @Brett - yes, copy|paste and too fast "add"

Comment: Ok, tried that but got this when running the upgrade command:

svn: E155019: Can't upgrade 'G:\Documents and Settings\myuser\Application Data' as it is not a working copy root
svn: E000002: Working copy database 'G:\Documents and Settings\myuser\Application Data\.svn\wc.db' not found svn: E720003: Additional errors:
svn: E720003: Can't open file 'G:\Documents and Settings\myuser\Application Data\.svn\entries': The system cannot find the path specified. -- The new `TortoiseSVN` was created before I ran this command but it is empty.

Comment: Also, not sure if it matters but wanted to mention that all my repositories are stored in `k:\SVN`.

Comment: Also, how do I get my old repositories acting as repositories again? Do I have to right click the folder and select `Create Repository Here` again? If so, will this keep all the old data files and history of changes etc?

Comment: @Brett - 1. you have to copy (and only copy) `c:\Documents and Settings\<USER>\Application Data\Subversion` tree into new location - it is **NOT** Working Copy 2. You can do nothing with *repositories*, only with **old Working Copies** (results of `svn co URL`), which have .svn hidden subdirs 3 Old repositories are still alive and can be used with old URLs

Comment: Well when I tried to do the copy you suggested I got those errors mentioned above. Not sure what my working copies have to do with the copy though - the only files I have in `c:\Documents and Settings\<USER>\Application Data\Subversion` are an `auth` folder and the following files: `config, README.txt, servers`. Sorry if I made it seem like my working copies were located in there; they are all located in a folder on my `D:` drive, the same place they were previously. For examples sake, let's just say they are located in `D:\Codebase`.

Comment: So you're self-hosting your SVN server? What version? Simply copying over `C:\Documents and Settings\<USER>\Application Data\Subversion\` to `G:\Documents and Settings\<USER>\Application Data\Subversion\` might not work until you tell your client (TortoiseSVN) and server to look there as well (update your `PATH` environment variable). Your checkouts need to be upgraded to the 1.8 format; TortoiseSVN should be able to do it for you. If that fails do a fresh checkout and manually merge any uncommitted changes using a comparison tool like [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php)

Comment: Yes, self-hosting it as I am the only person using it. I have just installed the old version for now and will worry about upgrading later I guess.